# Access Rights on Amazon Web Services' EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have recently created an EC2 account on Amazon Web Services.

I have created a key and am able to SSH into my box. I also have a few developers
working on the same box. I am wondering how I enforce access rights on my AMI
Instance as new developers work on this box?

Also, I have given the key I use to access the box, mykey.pem, to a developer so he
can access the box and am now wondering if that was the best thing to do. Is it
possible to issue new *.pem keys for each new developer and add/remove accordingly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into using the new (and beta) [AWS Identity and Access Management](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) service?  It provides the means to allow multiple users to access the same AWS resources without needing to share account keys.

Comment: Brent - that is fantastic. Exactly what I am looking for. But, now I have a developer with my current access key. Can I simply reissue the PEM key, making his invalid?

Comment: @Code yes recreate the key and all previous keys will become invalid.